# Eclipse update axis

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-axis

I'm using `Eclipse` `Juno` which comes with an axis include in version 1.4. This is installed in the folder:

> C:\Program Files\eclipse-jee-juno-SR1-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.axis_1.4.0.v201005080400

Can anyone tell me how I can update this? Where can I find the update for this? I already downloaded everything from

> http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/download.cgi

but this looks completely different.

I need to get from 1.4 to 1.6.2 because I’m using the functionality from axis to generate Web Service Client wish has a [bug in 1.4](https://success.clarizen.com/entries/24076632-v5-problems-with-Java-Axis-serialization-of-FieldValue-Value-XML-anyType-) and I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The [Axis2 Eclipse plugin documentation](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/eclipse/plugin-installation.html) explains how to install the most up to date versions of the plugins. It is not clear whether they have been tested with Juno.